# How to use pentaho kettle to load multiple files from s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, pentaho, kettle

I want to use the step `S3 CSV Input` to load multiple files from an s3 bucket then transform and load back into S3. But I can see this step support only one file at once and I need to supply the file names, is there any way to load all files at once by supplying only the bucket name i.e. `<s3-bucket-name>/*`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`S3-CSV-Input` is inspired by `CSV-Input` and doesn't support multi-file-processing like `Text-File-Input` does, for example.  You'll have to [retrieve the  filenames](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ls.html) first, so you can loop over the filename list as you would do with `CSV-Input`.

Comment: I used `Execute Shell script` to get list of all files in bucket, how can I pass the stdout output to a loop ?

Comment: Redirect aws stdout to a temporary file, use e.g. `Text-File-Input` to extract filenames, pass the filenames via `Copy-Rows-To-Result` to the looping transformation (advanced option "execute for every input row"). Define a parameter FILENAME and initialize it on the parameters setting page of your transformation.  Don't forget to enable advanced option "Copy previous results to parameters". Have fun with [Kettle](http://forums.pentaho.com/forumdisplay.php?135-Pentaho-Data-Integration-Kettle).

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

**AWS CLI method**

1. Write a simple shell script that calls AWS CLI. Put it in your path. Call it `s3.sh`

   ```
   aws s3 ls s3://bucket.name/path | cut -c32-
   ```

   In PDI:
2. Generate Rows: `Limit` 1, Fields: `Name`: process, `Type`: String, `Value` s3.sh
3. Execute a Process: `Process field`: process, `Output Line Delimiter` |
4. Split Field to Rows: `Field to split`: Result output. `Delimiter` | `New field name`: filename
5. S3 CSV Input: `The filename field`: filename

**S3 Local Sync**

Mount the S3 directory to a local directory, using [s3fs](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse)

If you have many large files in that bucket directory, it wouldn't work so fast...well it might be okay if your PDI runs on an Amazon machine

Then use the standard file reading tools

```
$ s3fs my-bucket.example.com/path/ ~/my-s3-files -o use_path_request_style -o url=https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```